# Why can't I access some members of an abstract class in this kotlin code?

Tags: class, kotlin, inheritance

In the code below I can access all overridden members of the abstract class, but not its own members.

```
     interface Collection<T: Any> {
        val count: Int
    
        val isEmpty: Boolean
            get() = count == 0
    
           }
    
    
    interface Heap<T: Any> : Collection<T> {
    
        fun peek(): T?
    }
    
    abstract class AbstractHeap<T: Any>() : Heap<T> {
       
        var elements: ArrayList<T> = ArrayList<T>()
    
        override val count: Int
            get() = elements.size
    
        override fun peek(): T? = elements.firstOrNull()
    ...
    }
    class ComparableHeapImpl<T : Comparable<T>> :
        AbstractHeap<T>() {
    
        companion object {
            fun <T : Comparable<T>> create(
                elements: ArrayList<T>
            ): Heap<T> {
                val heap = ComparableHeapImpl<T>()
                heap.heapify(elements)
                return heap
            }
        }
    
    }
```

I cannot access `elements` as below

```
    fun main() {
        val array = arrayListOf(1, 12, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7)
        val test = ComparableHeapImpl.create(array)


        val a = test.elements[0]  // This won't work.
    

}
```

But in this code I wrote:

```
    abstract class Test{
        val i = 1
        fun test(){ println("nothing")}
    }
    class Test1: Test(){
        companion object {
            val a = Test1()
            fun create(): Test1 = a
        }
    }


fun main() {
val test = Test1.create()

    test.test() // This works fine.
    println(test.i) // And this works fine.


}
```

Everything works fine. I cannot make sense of this. Oh, and I am using android studio arctic firefox patch 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test` variable here:

```kotlin
val test = ComparableHeapImpl.create(array)
```

is not of type `AbstractHeap<Int>`, it is of type `Heap<Int>` (by definition of `ComparableHeapImpl.create`). This is why you cannot access `elements` - it's not part of the `Heap` interface.

If you want to access the `elements` variable, you have several options:

1. make it part of the `Heap` interface
2. make `create` return `AbstractHeap` (or `ComparableHeapImpl`, which would be more logical for this factory function)
3. cast `test` to `AbstractHeap` or `ComparableHeapImpl`

Why do you want to access this property from outside, though? IMO, you should provide all the public methods/properties that make sense for the usage of your heaps in the `Heap` interface, but this one most likely should be `private` (or maybe `protected`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I didn't write this code and When I saw elements isn't private I wanted to access it to see if I could. I am learning kotlin you know.

Comment: I see, well now you know :) Have fun learning Kotlin!